# Write a function reversing the array elements of the first and last column

Tags: c, arrays

Data: array of real numbers with dimensions of N lines, M columns. Write a function reversing the array elements of the first and last column. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: People will be more willing to help if you show your attempt.

Comment: `Type temp = array[row][first]; array[row][first] = array[row][last]; array[row][last] = temp;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You should show your best effort, and explain where you're having problems.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that C stores matrices row-wise i.e. A[N][M] is the matrix with N rows and M columns.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 4
#define M 4
int main() {
    int i, j, temp;
    int A[N][M] =
            {
                    {1, 2, 3, 4},
                    {5, 6, 7, 8},
                    {9, 1, 2, 3},
                    {4, 5, 6, 7}
            };
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            printf("%d", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) {
        temp = A[i][0];
        A[i][0] = A[N - 1 - i][0];
        A[N - 1 - i][0] = temp;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) {
        temp = A[i][M - 1];
        A[i][M - 1] = A[N - 1 - i][M - 1];
        A[N - 1 - i][M - 1] = temp;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            printf("%d", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
1234
5678
9123
4567

4237
9673
5128
1564
```

Comment: No idea for the downvote other than you generally want to require the questioner to present their effort before providing a solution (SO isn't intended as a coding service). That said, the only *nits* I would have is you never want to use the *variadic* `printf` function to output a single character. Instead, use an appropriate *character-output* function (e.g. `putchar ('\n');`) to output the `'\n'` character. Also, from a *style* standpoint, C generally reserves ALLCAPS for constants and macros while using lower-case for variable names (e.g. `int a[N][M]`) Entirely up to you.

Comment: I'd be tempted to use `static void dump_array(int N, int M, int A[N][M]) {     for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) printf("%3d", A[i][j]); putchar('\n'); }` or similar and call that twice.  I'd probably also write a small function to reverse the order of the elements in a column of a matrix, and call that twice.  It would save repetition in `main()`. By making the functions `static`, the compiler might use its heuristics to determine that they should be inlined. You could add `inline` (`static inline void …`) to give the compiler a hint.